# Making R Markdown file work in Kaggle notebook

Tags: r, kaggle

I'm attempting to run my .rmd case study into a Kaggle notebook. Every time I run the "`Save % Run All (Commit)`" button it fails. https://www.kaggle.com/code/jordanomarroche/da-course-case-study/comments for my script. Ultimately I want this file to look like (visualizations/code chunks/etc) it does when i run knitR in RStudio.

Any help will be greatly appreciated as this is my capstone project for a DA course and I'm having difficulty getting my code to work in Kaggle!

**Screenshot**
[image]

I tried changing the read_csv file to the /...input directory but it still managed to fail when commiting.

**Screenshot**
[image] - Log of my version attempting to run.

Comment: Most likely issue: The duplicated double quote `""` in `read.csv`, i.e. `books_df <- read_csv(""/...."` should be `books_df <- read_csv("/...."`

Comment: @stefan Wow! Of course it was. Thank you so much. It ran successfully.